# conditions for a field to appear in odoo 14

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I'd like field A to appear only if field B has a given value

field B doesn't belong to the same model, it belongs to a model connected through a many2one relationship

How do I write the contents of the `attrs` attribute for field A in the form ?

Until now I used

```
<field name="A"...
attrs="{'invisible': [('B', '=', 'some_value')
```

But until now both A and B belonged to the same model

Answer (score 1):

Field used in `attrs` must be present in view

You can't use dotted field names because Odoo will raise an error if the field name contain `.` when validating the view definition:

```
Invalid composed field %(definition)s in %(use)s (attrs.invisible ...)
```

There is an exception for list sub-views (One2many/Many2many display in a form view) where you can use `parent.field_name`

Answer (score 1):

ok, I reply to myself

First, in the model:

```
field_B = field.fieldtype(related='many2one_field.field_b')
```

Then, in the form view:

```
<field name="field_B" invisible="1"/>
```

and then

```
<field name="field_A" ...
        attrs="{'invisible': [('field_B', '=', 'some_value')]}">
```